# Show Records from the Top in a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I am writing an app in which *i am fetching list of Facebook Friends those birthdays in next 30 days*, and i am able to fetch that as well.

but i am **facing very small problem**

I saw if i have more than 4 records in a List then i am getting list of friends from the top, and if i have 1 or 2 records in a List then i am getting results at bottom, like in below screen shot:

Please tell me how can i resolve this issue, i w**ant to show these records on top not at bottom...**

activityfb_friends.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/friends_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    android:layout_above="@+id/greeting"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/greeting"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/greet"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

listfb_friends.xml:

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:background="@drawable/btn_background"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/friend_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:background="@drawable/image_background"
    android:padding="3dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:src="@drawable/img"/>
</RelativeLayout> 

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/friend_item"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/friend_item"
    android:textColor="#324e87"
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="sans" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dob"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/name"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/friend_item"
    android:textColor="#343434"
    android:textSize="15dip"
    />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the layout of `@+id/friends_list`.  You've set its `layout_height="wrap_content"`, and to `layout_above="@+id/greeting"`.  This means it will only be as large as it needs to to fit the contained items, and it will appear just above the greeting button (which you've anchored to the bottom of the container).

The simplest solution is to remove `layout_above` and replace it with `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`.  This will anchor the list to the top of the container, rather than just above the greeting image button.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` in the the list view who's id is friends_list